# Chapterthumb only at first page of chapter

Tags: koma-script, chapterthumb

I would like to include a chapterthumb in my document. However it only appears on the first page of the chapter. Thank you for your help :).

This is what I included:

```
\usepackage{chapterthumb}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setheadsepline{0.2pt}
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalsize}
```

and

```
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}
```

Cheers Kirsten

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which version of `chapterthumb.sty` do you use? Which version of KOMA-Script do you use? Please make your code snippets compilable ...

Answer (score 2):

Well, with the current version of `chapterthumb.sty` (download file [`KOMA-Script-6-Buch-Beispielcode.zip` from web page https://komascript.de/](https://komascript.de/komascriptbuch6examples) and copy file `chapterthumb.sty` from `\KOMA-Script-6-Buch-Beispielcode.zip\KOMA-Script-6\Anhang-B\source`) to your computer into a new directory.

Copy the following code into the same directory:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext} % <===================== dummy text
\usepackage{chapterthumb}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Am Anfang beginnt es}\dots
\Blindtext \Blindtext \Blindtext % <============= dummy text
\chapter{weiter}\dots
\chapter{und weiter}\dots
\chapter{und noch weiter}\dots
\chapter{Und immer weiter}\dots
\chapter{Geht die Reise}\dots
\chapter{Hinaus}\dots
\chapter{Und weiter hinaus}\dots
\chapter{Immer weiter hinaus}\dots
\chapter{Bis zum Ende}
\end{document}
```

Please see that I added package `blindtext` to get some dummy text for the first chapter. Compile three time and you get the result for page 1:

[image: page 1]

and for page 3:

[image]

Comment: The KOMA-Script examples from the book are also part of a complet MiKTeX or TeX Live installation. The `chapterthumb.sty` should be located in `<path to your distribution>/doc/info/koma-script-examples/Anhang-B/source`.